# Relative phase between neighbouring states in continous parameter space

Tags: topology, topological-phase

The relative phase of two quantum states $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ can be written, $$\gamma_{12}=-\text{arg}\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle=-\text{arg}\big[|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|e^{-i\gamma_{12}}\big].$$
If these two states are very close to each other then,
$$e^{-i\Delta\gamma}=\frac{\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R+dR)\rangle}{|\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R+dR)\rangle|}.$$
From this one is supposed to be able to find,
$$\Delta\gamma=i\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(R)\rangle dR.$$
This can be found in some power points when searching for Berry phase as relative phase and in the book *A short course on topological insulators - Asbóth*, link: http://optics.szfki.kfki.hu/~asboth/topins_course/book.pdf

See page 25 of the book.
I get something slightly different.

**Attempt at solution:**

Assuming the phase between two neighbouring states is small we can expand the left side, $$e^{-i\Delta\gamma}=1-i\Delta\gamma.$$
We can also expand the ket, $$|\psi(R+dR)\rangle=|\psi(R)\rangle +\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR.$$
Together then I get,
$$1-i\Delta\gamma=\frac{\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle +\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR}{|\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle +\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR|}.$$
It is only possible to get the correct solution if the denominator can be removed (equals 1).

**Why is** $|\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle +\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR|=1$ **to first order in** $dR$?

Comment: Use the fact that $|\psi(R)\rangle$ and $|\psi(R + dR)\rangle$ have to be normalized, i.e. $\langle \psi(R) | \psi(R) \rangle = \langle \psi(R+ dR) | \psi(R + dR) \rangle = 1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Obviously  $|\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle +\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR|=|1+\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR|$. But where can I make use of the second normalization condition? It does not appear anywhere.

Comment: Well, if you do the Taylor expansion of the second normalization condition in terms of $dR$ then you will find a term involving $\langle \psi(R) | \nabla_R | \psi(r) \rangle$, which also appears in your denominator.

Comment: Yes, sure but it does not help. $1=\langle\psi(R+dR)|\psi(R+dR)\rangle $ gives, $0=\langle \psi|\nabla \psi\rangle dR+ \langle \nabla\psi|\psi\rangle dR$.

Comment: Expand the denominator also to first order in dR and you get the exact same quantity as on the RHS of that equation (plus 1).

Comment: Actually one can prove that $\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR$ is purely imaginary and then the absolute value is $\sqrt{1+...dR^2}=1.$ to first order.

Comment: Well, yes, that is the point. So what's the problem? The denominator is 1 to first order in dR.

Comment: No problem at all! I see it now! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR $ is purely imaginary because, $$0=\nabla_R\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle=\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R\psi(R)\rangle+\langle\nabla_R\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle=$$
$$=\langle\nabla_R\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle+\langle\nabla_R\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle^*.$$
The absolute value of $a+ib$ is $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$. Therfore, $$|\langle\psi(R)|\psi(R)\rangle +\langle\psi(R)|\nabla_R|\psi(r)\rangle dR|=\sqrt{1+O(dR^2)}=1.$$